# Mysql get percentage change grouped by user

Tags: mysql, sql

I am not an expert in `sql` and I would want some help in getting percentage change for every `contract_address`.

What I want to achieve

Get the percentage change of price `price` in 7 days using `created_at`.

```sql
-- Adminer 4.8.1 MySQL 5.5.5-10.4.10-MariaDB dump

SET NAMES utf8;
SET time_zone = '+00:00';
SET foreign_key_checks = 0;
SET sql_mode = 'NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO';

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `nft_market_trade`;
CREATE TABLE `nft_market_trade` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `contract_address` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `token_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `price` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `amount` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `type` enum('F','A') DEFAULT NULL,
  `from_address` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `to_address` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `block_number` mediumtext DEFAULT NULL,
  `tx_hash` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `event` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_at` datetime DEFAULT current_timestamp(),
  `updated_at` datetime DEFAULT current_timestamp(),
  `timestamp` mediumtext DEFAULT NULL,
  `fee_artist_portion` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `fee_treasury_portion` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `auction_id` mediumtext DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO `nft_market_trade` (`id`, `contract_address`, `token_id`, `price`, `amount`, `type`, `from_address`, `to_address`, `block_number`, `tx_hash`, `event`, `created_at`, `updated_at`, `timestamp`, `fee_artist_portion`, `fee_treasury_portion`, `auction_id`) VALUES
(342,   '0xeed69d5ac882bbecb7449fe31e916a3c69b3c27a',   3,  0.000003,   1,  'F',    '0x68cb4d2da9323586c11d58cc3c22f96282319050',   '0x4091320130802794fc301642b8d61d090e419477',   '97325503', '0x0648cf42ae8683baedda860c0b64fa061abc06d3353f898d042e118fb8537b48',   'SOLD', '2022-08-27 06:14:54',  '2022-07-27 06:14:54',  '1658902087',   0.00000006, 0.00000006, NULL),
(343,   '0xeed69d5ac882bbecb7449fe31e916a3c69b3c27a',   3,  0.000003,   1,  'F',    '0x68cb4d2da9323586c11d58cc3c22f96282319050',   '0xb7204b9862d2302d2109d38d548111c966ef78ee',   '97322182', '0x83ae44b08d1be5060a1a7d0bd6b82878b2a08734adacc392afdf57f32dde8046',   'PLACE',    '2022-08-27 06:14:56',  '2022-07-27 06:14:56',  '1658898762',   0,  0,  NULL),
(344,   '0xeed69d5ac882bbecb7449fe31e916a3c69b3c27a',   3,  3.5,    1,  'F',    '0x4091320130802794fc301642b8d61d090e419477',   '0xb7204b9862d2302d2109d38d548111c966ef78ee',   '97326062', '0xf9ccc91d53f696594ab04e6782a30c83a6e11663e641acf2999ca5236df710ad',   'PLACE',    '2022-08-27 06:17:42',  '2022-07-27 06:17:42',  '1658902646',   0,  0,  NULL),
(345,   '0xeed69d5ac882bbecb7449fe31e916a3c69b3c27a',   3,  3.5,    1,  'F',    '0x4091320130802794fc301642b8d61d090e419477',   '0x68cb4d2da9323586c11d58cc3c22f96282319050',   '97326730', '0xab4db021609514cb50846baa08124667634b80902cb9d1f3bb9189239980d218',   'SOLD', '2022-08-27 06:28:54',  '2022-07-27 06:28:54',  '1658903314',   0.07,   0.07,   NULL),
(346,   '0xeed69d5ac882bbecb7449fe31e916a3c69b3c27a',   3,  3.5,    1,  'F',    '0x68cb4d2da9323586c11d58cc3c22f96282319050',   '0x2b08e3ca40d615606c5068db8b66f41f460da811',   '97328265', '0xa252f96edb41a0c6c7c66d7316b40cf9101b629e6342f4043ffce9c1e9322b86',   'PLACE',    '2022-08-27 06:54:15',  '2022-07-27 06:54:15',  '1658904850',   0,  0,  NULL)
```

Here is what I have tried

```sql
SELECT a.contract_address, a.price, a.event, a.created_at, max(price) - min(price) / min(price) * 100 as percentchange
FROM `nft_market_trade` a
WHERE a.event = "SOLD"
AND created_at >= now() - interval 7 day
group by a.contract_address;
```

Problem with my implementation is the percentage is calculated before the `where` clause, i.e. I am getting the percentage change before applying where clause.

Here is sqlfiddle link to my query. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/40809f5d/8

I would appreciate some help

Comment: What is the value you expect for the percentchange column?

Comment: @GRIV, in this example, 0% since there is 1 return row

Answer (score 1):

You can write a subquery within your percentage change calculation to achieve this then `GROUP BY` contract_address. Optionally, you can remove the `ROUND` function to get a more detailed value.

```
SELECT contract_address,
       price,
       event,
       created_at,
       round(price * 100 / (SELECT SUM(price)
                            FROM   nft_market_trade
                            WHERE  event = "SOLD"
                                   AND created_at >= now() - interval 7 day
                                   GROUP BY contract_address), 2)
       as
       percentchange
From   nft_market_trade
WHERE  event = "SOLD"
       AND created_at >= now() - interval 7 day
GROUP  BY contract_address
```

> Output: 0%

See [Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=40fbdf4531fe849a61f801dfeb482241).

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer. Does this include negative and positive change?

Comment: Yes it will handle negative change. One thing I do want to clarify is, the `GROUP BY` will return the earliest entry in the table (`ID` **342** even though **345** has been **created** and **SOLD** within the **last 7 days**) is this what you want?

Comment: This is no problem, since I do not need ordering, another this is. when a user has not `sold` i.e in the last 24 hours, we should return 0%

Comment: OK my answer should work then, thanks for the clarification. I've added another `GROUP BY` to the subquery. You might run into an issue with the `ROUNDING` though, you might need to remove it since you're dealing with large monetary transaction values.